# How to install npm on tiny core linux

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, tiny-core-linux

i was able to install nodejs from appbrowser-cli  but it has not installed npm
How do i install npm on tinycore linux ?

I tried many things but none worked out.

Comment: `tce-load -w -i nodejs.tcz` appears to work.

Answer (score 5):

Below are the steps to install node/npm from source (OSX/linux)

NOTE - this install gives you both node as well as npm,
       they come together per release.

to start fresh remove prior node and npm installs as well as these :

```
sudo mv ~/.npmrc ~/.npmrc_ignore
sudo mv ~/.npm   ~/.npm_ignore
sudo mv ~/tmp    ~/tmp_ignore
sudo mv ~/.npm-init.js ~/.npm-init.js_ignore
```

download source from :  https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/

_OR_specific releases at :  https://nodejs.org/download/release/

```
cd node-v6.3.1  #  <-- download expands to this temp dir
```

You may/should issue all following cmds as yourself NOT root (sudo)

Pick one of these NODE_PARENT locations to define where node gets installed into :

```
export NODE_PARENT=/some/desired/install/path_goes_here
export NODE_PARENT=/usr/local/bin/nodejs   # use this ONLY if you MUST install as root (sudo)
export NODE_PARENT=${HOME}/node-v6.3.1 # Recommended - owned by you NOT root

export PATH=${NODE_PARENT}/bin:${PATH} # jack up PATH for executables
export NODE_PATH=${NODE_PARENT}/lib/node_modules # so node itself can find its modules dir

./configure --prefix=${NODE_PARENT}

make
make install
```

which puts it into dir defined by above --prefix

when you use syntax :  npm install -g some_cool_module
the -g for global installs it into dir $NODE_PATH and not your $PWD

IMPORTANT - put above three  export xxx=yyy
commands into your ~/.bashrc or some such to persist these environment variable changes

If you had a prior install of node you may want to copy over previously installed modules into new location :

```
~/node-v6.3.1/lib/node_modules/
```

or do fresh module installs using npm install -g xxxx

Answer (score 3):

`tce-load -w -i appbrowser-cli.tcz`
`appbrowser-cli`

click S

search for node package

Install nodejs

If you see permission denied message on npm : use following commands

`cd /mnt/sda1/tmp/tcloop`
`cp -r nodejs-v0.10.28 /home/nodejs`
`alias npm='node /home/nodejs/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js'`

Answer (score 1):

Install nodejs via package manager for tinycore

`$ tce-load -w -i appbrowser-cli.tcz`
`$ appbrowser-cli`
this will open command line package manager, search for node and install

Comment: Just in case you want to see tiny core repo list
http://repo.tinycorelinux.net/6.x/x86/tcz/

Answer (score 0):

ok the problem is it installed npm but some how it's on read only file system.
I had to make a copy of whole folder and put a symlink to make it work